# How to setup replication(Master/slave) in MySQL 5.5.20?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I have two servers both running on MySQL 5.5.20 and I want to setup replication, so every update/insert on Master would reflect immediately on Slave machine.

I tried following this tutorial ([I used instructions given on this website.](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication)) but it is not working. I found that after doing all this I couldn't ... (((Please update this part with your experiences)))

Could you please suggest me a tested and an efficient way to do this in MySQL 5.5.20?

Comment: Hi Vinny. Can you outline what you tried from the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html), and expound on what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: I used instructions given on this website. http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication.

Comment: Hi Vinny, I think this is too broad of a scope for this Site. If you adjusted the question to be specifically what went wrong with the guide you followed, we could better help you.

Comment: Hi Vinny, can you update the question by clicking "edit" above and adding detail where I put this phrase `(((Please update this part with your experiences)))`? Otherwise we're going to have to close this as too localized, because you won't be able to help others that had the same problems as you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please create this script

Fron the Linux prompt, open up an editor like vi

```
vi /root/CreateMySQLSlave.sh
```

and add these lines to it

```
MYSQL_MASTER_HOST=10.1.2.20
MYSQL_SLAVE_HOST=10.1.2.30
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
MYSQL_MASTER_CONN="-h${MYSQL_MASTER_HOST} ${MYSQL_CONN}"
MYSQL_SLAVE_CONN="-h${MYSQL_SLAVE_HOST} ${MYSQL_CONN}"

MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--master-data=1"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --single-transaction"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --routines"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --triggers"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --flush-privileges"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --all-databases"

CREATE_REPL_USER="GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO repluser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'replpass'"
mysql ${MYSQL_MASTER_CONN} -AN -e"${CREATE_REPL_USER}"

RELOAD_FILE=/root/MySQLData.sql
echo "STOP SLAVE;" > ${RELOAD_FILE}
echo "CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='${MYSQL_MASTER_HOST}'," >> ${RELOAD_FILE}
echo "master_port=3306," >> ${RELOAD_FILE}
echo "master_user='repluser'," >> ${RELOAD_FILE}
echo "master_password='replpass'," >> ${RELOAD_FILE}
echo "master_log_file='dummy-file'," >> ${RELOAD_FILE}
echo "master_log_pos=1;" >> ${RELOAD_FILE}
mysqldump ${MYSQL_MASTER_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} >> ${RELOAD_FILE}
echo "START SLAVE;" >> ${RELOAD_FILE}

mysql ${MYSQL_SLAVE_CONN} -A < ${RELOAD_FILE}
```

Next, make the file executable and run it

```
chmod +x /root/CreateMySQLSlave.sh
/root/CreateMySQLSlave.sh
```

That's it !!!

Make sure you set the IP Address for `MYSQL_MASTER_HOST` and `MYSQL_SLAVE_HOST`

By the way, don't worry about the `dummy-file` in the master_log_file parameter for `CHANGE MASTER TO`. Line 29 of the dump file should have the correct setting there due to the `--master-data=1`. You can see it by doing this to the dump file

```
head -29 /root/MySQLData.sql | tail -1
```

Make sure binary logging is already enabled on the master. Here is how you can tell: run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`. If you get nothing back, you need to enable it like this:

Add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

then restart mysql

OK that takes care of binary logging for the Master.

You also need to make sure the Master and the Slave have different server IDs. Here is how you can tell:

Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';` If the result comes up as `1`, you must set it explicitly.

Goto the Master and add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id=1
```

Goto the Slave and add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2
```

The main thing here is to make sure `server_id` is explicitly set in my.cnf on both Master and Slave. You must also make sure the server_id values are different from all other servers involved in the replication topology.

If you are new to this, have a sysadmin join you to do this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by run this script?? Where should i run it? (sorry i am a very novice user)

Comment: I gave the lines for a script in my answer to create a slave on another machine running mysql. You need to create a file on the DB server with these lines, make the script executable (chmod +x) and run the script as given. By the way, what OS are you using, Windows or Linux ???

Comment: CentOS 6 and MySQL5.5.20

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an explanatory answer.But, the problem is, The data has already been transferred from DB1 to DB2. I only need a way to set up auto-replication from Master to Slave. Please tell me what changes to be done in "my.cnf"

Comment: I tried your CreateMySQLSlave.sh on ubuntu 14, mysql 5.6, and it just hangs and I had to kill it unfortuatnely. I am assuming you run this script on the slave server, not the master.  It is also unclear if you should run the script first, or do the steps that you list after the script first.

Comment: Where wouild we specify which particular schema should be replicated?  Don't we need to dump it on the master, and import it into he slave, once the base configuration is done?